# Filtering Tabs in a Custom Post Type's Edit Page

Tags: post-meta, metabox, tabs

I am using LearnDash to create courses on WordPress.

A key thing is that I have other non-admin instructors that will also help me create lessons.

The thing is, the lesson edit page has a "Settings" tab (see image) that has controls that I **DO NOT** want non-admin instructors to access. In other words, I want to filter away the "Settings" tab and only keep access to the "Lesson Page" tab for instructor role.

I don't know what filter hook can do that. I tried looking into the LearnDash source code but I can't seem to find a solution.

[image: lesson edit page has settings tab]

Comment: I'm not a learndash expert, and 3rd party software is offtopic.  You may want to check their documentation...start on this page: https://www.learndash.com/support/docs/core/lessons/lesson-settings.